# Getting the Text Size of a Spannable TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable

I have a button which increases the size of selected text when clicked. I want it to increase to a certain size, e.g. 36sp, then after that, it stops. I am using a `RelativeSizeSpan` for this. `text.getTextSize()` seems to be returning a constant value, which looks like the default/overall size. How can I get the size of the selected Text?

```
private void makeChanges(float size) {
    Log.d("EditText", "makeChanges Text Size: " + text.getTextSize());

    str.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(size),
                    selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    text.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: That is because `getTextSize()` returns the default value for the `TextView`. What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Because you are using `RelativeSizeSpan` I do not think that you can get an absolute size like "36sp". You will need to do the math yourself. If you were to use `AbsoluteSizeSpan` then you could get the absolute size of the selected text.

Comment: @Barns I want to get the text size of the currently selected text by the user, as a result, limit them to how much they can increase the text

Comment: @Barns I want the user to increase the text size and decrease it how ever they want. From my understanding of `AbsoluteSizeSpan` it sets fixed sizes. This was my initial approach, to set a global variable and add to it when ever the user increases the size and decrease it otherwise. The problem I encountered is that the global variable remains the same even if the selected text changes. Then I decided to use `RelativeSizeSpan`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closer at your code you can notice that RelativeSizeSpan receives a float value, which increases the size of your text by a that given percentage. The default value is in pixels. If you need the modified size, you need to get the default value and multiply it by `float size` variable. If that factor changes during runtime, you can access it the with following methods

The following code is a demonstration, tweak it for your use. It is tested with a debugger and it shows correct value.

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("some nice text goes here.");
    ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(3.0f), 5, 10, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    TextView tView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    tView.setText(ss);

    // default size - before span
    int pixelsPrevious = (int) tView.getTextSize();

    // spanned text
    Spanned spanned = (Spanned) tView.getText();
    RelativeSizeSpan[] spanArray = spanned.getSpans(0, spanned.length(), RelativeSizeSpan.class);

    // you are looking for this value.
    int pixelsNew = (int) (pixelsPrevious * spanArray[0].getSizeChange());
```